# How to scroll to top of modal using c# and blazor

Tags: c#, html, css, modal-dialog, blazor-server-side

I noticed that when I open and close my modals on a small screen, it opens where I last closed it - which would be the bottom of the modal. A form shouldn't really open at the bottom so I'm trying to reset the modal back to the top.

I have temporarily added an `<a>` anchor tag and referenced the top of the page but this is not very efficient and it adds a #ect to the URL which references the anchor tag which looks horrible.

I'm not using Javascript just html css and c# and blazor.

```
       .backgroundPopupBox {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

.addProductPopupBox {
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 28px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}



/* Browsers Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px; /*for vertical scrollbar */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background: #777;
    }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

HTML PAGE

```
    @page "/test"


<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary addButton" @onclick="@(e => newProductComponent.Open())">Add <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>


<NewProduct @ref="newProductComponent"></NewProduct>

@code {
    private NewProduct? newProductComponent { get; set; }


}
```

MODAL

```
   <div class="modal @ModalClass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:@ModalDisplay">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="backgroundPopupBox">
            <div class="addProductPopupBox">
                <h2 id="top">No overscroll chaining</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn-secondary button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a href="/test#top" target="_top">Go to top</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private Guid Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    private string ModalDisplay = "none;";
    private string ModalClass = "";

    public void Open()
    {
        ModalDisplay = "block;";
        ModalClass = "Show";
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void Close()
    {
        ModalDisplay = "none";
        ModalClass = "";
        StateHasChanged();
    } 
}
```

Is it possible to reset the modal completely on close so that when I click on a button and open the modal it opens at the top of the form not the bottom where it is closed.

Comment: Try anchor links: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-anchor-link-to-jump-to-a-specific-part-of-a-page.html

It looks like you are missing # in href="section2"

Comment: When I add the # to the start of the href it takes me to index page. Without the # it says Sorry, there's nothing at this address. This is my issue it cant seem to find where its meant to go

Comment: Ok update: I have found that adding <a href="/pageName#section2" target="_top">Go to Section 2</a> WORKS!! Downside the modal does not have a pageName as it is a modal

Comment: Be careful, Java is not the same language as JavaScript (JS).

Comment: Have you tried setting focus to the first element in the modal after it opens?

Comment: @MisterMagoo and how would this be done? Keep in mind I can't use Javascript

Comment: You can capture an ElementReference for your `h2` and invoke its `FocusAsync` method in `OnAfterRenderAsync(true)`  - the default action for this is to focus the element and scroll it into view.

Comment: @Imogen "Is it possible to reset the modal completely": I guess by wrapping all your modal by an `@if(IsDisplayModal){ modal razor code }` should reset what you want everytime you set `IsDisplayModal` back to true. Basically, use the Blazor way for render management instead of CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are handling the display of the modal with CSS, the browser should remember where you left the scroll bar. If you use the rendering system of Blazor (which destroys and recreates the elements every time), the browser shouldn't be able to keep track of the modal scrollbar status between renders.

```
@if(IsDisplayModal)
{
  /*Modal razor code*/
}

@code{
  public bool IsDisplayModal { get; set;} = false;
}
```